# Tax exempt non-retirement investment

Tags: united-states, income-tax, investing

So I am attempting to generate ways to nickle and dime Uncle Sam.

Currently a little over half of my annual income is in rental income so it's pretax until the end of the year. I would LOVE to come up with a tax deferred investment battlefield for my little green soldiers.

So my question is....

Is there a tax free investment that I can put pre-tax rental income into in order to stick it to my government hard and fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only non-retirement, tax-advantaged accounts I'm aware of are:

- [HSA accounts](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/consumer-health/in-depth/health-savings-accounts/art-20044058).
- [529 accounts](http://www.savingforcollege.com/intro_to_529s/what-is-a-529-plan.php).

You can also invest in government bonds. They have lower returns than stocks over the long run, but are federal tax-free. For most states, they are also state tax-free if you buy bonds from the state you're a resident of.